# CSRF issues when integrating TinyMCE image upload with CakePHP 3.8

Tags: cakephp, tinymce, cakephp-3.0, csrf

I'm using CakePHP 3.8 to create a CMS for a website. I need a simple WYSIWYG editor with image upload.  I'd previously used CKEditor, but was having problems getting the image upload working, so thought I'd try TinyMCE instead.

So, I downloaded TinyMCE 5 (with all standard plugins), linked it in in the head section of my page, and created a form with a TinyMCE textarea like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>New Page</legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Flash->render();
        echo $this->Form->create($newpage);
        echo $this->Form->control('title');
        echo $this->Form->control('content', 
                      array('label' => 'Page Content',
                            'type' => 'textarea', 
                            'id' => 'editor_area'));
        echo $this->Form->button('Save');
        echo $this->Form->end();
    ?>
</fieldset>

<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'#editor_area',
        height: 500,
        menubar: false,
        images_upload_url: '<?php echo IMG_UPLOAD_URL ?>',
        toolbar: [
            'undo redo | cut copy paste | styleselect | bold italic underline removeformat | alignleft aligncenter alignright | charmap | bullist numlist | link image'
        ],
        plugins: ['advlist lists link autolink image charmap imagetools code']
    });
</script>
```

This works fine, text area appears with the editor etc. The upload url in `images_upload_url` points to the following `UploadsController.php` (I've left out the details for brevity; can add them in if needed):

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class UploadsController extends AppController
{

    public function uploadImage() {

        $result = array();
        $result['success'] = 'success';

        // Process file upload

        return $this->response->withType('application/json')
                    ->withStringBody(json_encode($result));

    }

}
```

When I upload an image, I get the following error in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

The output from CakePHP shows the error:

```
Error: CSRF token mismatch.
```

The debugger shows that the POST includes the following:

```
Cookie: CAKEPHP=dvsktjv7vp8la5nv7dv19634d1; csrfToken=53e5718e13a1e963d51f9c93c48471a478b35c02b565d6f0699cd2a335775c2b17986cfc2cc587ff7343a6573e3eb2e498a9cb962397599c023417d1dfa9506c; ckCsrfToken=7l2PEC0g06819qQcLwdX5ul7E7jNRa3r61jENt2x
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

(Or if there's a more straightforward way to include a free/inexpensive WYSIWYG editor with a decent image/file uploader, I'm open to suggestions! It's a website for a school, so budget is very small and can't be a monthly cost.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cookie data is only one part of the CSRF protection mechanism, the client needs to send the CSRF token in either the request data or the `X-CSRF-Token` header too.

I'm not overly familiar with TinyMCE image uploads, but looking at the docs, you'll probably need a custom upload handler, where you can add additional data, the CSRF token that is.

Taking [**the example from the TinyMCE docs**](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_handler), the handler could look something like this, where the CSRF token is appended to the form data:

```js
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
    var xhr, formData;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    xhr.open('POST', <?= json_encode(IMG_UPLOAD_URL) ?>);

    xhr.onload = function() {
        var json;

        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
            return;
        }

        json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
            failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
            return;
        }

        success(json.location);
    };

    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
    // append CSRF token in the form data
    formData.append('_csrfToken', <?= json_encode($this->request->getParam('_csrfToken')) ?>);

    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Also according to the docs the response JSON must contain a property named `location` that contains the web path to the uploaded file, that might be in the code that you've left out, mentioning it just in case.

See also

- **[TinyMCE Docs > Introduction & getting started > Uploading images and files](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/)**
- **[TinyMCE Docs > Configuration reference > Image & file upload options > images_upload_handler](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_handler)**
- **[Cookbook > Security > Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-middleware)**

Comment: I find your solution really helpful, but would you mind adding a small brief on how to remove image on deleting on TinyMCE, with this, it looks like the images remain there forever.

Comment: @SarojShrestha I don't know what exactly you're referring to, but it sounds like it's unrelated, and should probably be explained in a separate question.